# What is the definition ties of Kinship?

Tags: sunnah, definitions

Which family members fall under kinship?

If a person has a big family, does it mean he has to tie Kinship with all aunts, uncles and cousins?

Or is holding ties of Kinship with only maternal relatives fine?

Answer (score 1):

Ties of kinship which can also be called as devotion to relatives (Seleh-Rahem) is regarded as a very significant issue from the perspective of Islam, as if it is haram to abort this relation (coming and going) to them.

Kinship or actually relatives consists of all the ones who are in the levels/layers of heir, among:

- Parents
- Grandparents
- Uncles
- Aunts
- Their children

**Pay heed that all of them are related to both maternal/paternal sides.**

Of course, apparently, having relationship/tie doesn’t mean always to have a heavy relationship with all of them, but it means that you have (even its minimum deal) a tie as if -- based on the Orf (custom)-- you have not aborted that, although e.g. you can have a simple phone calling, and so on.

---

**Sources (and more accurate information):**

- en.wikishia.net/view/Silat_al-rahim (English)
- [www.islamquest.net/fr/archive/question/fa3813](http://www.islamquest.net/fr/archive/question/fa3813) (in French)
- [https://article.tebyan.net](https://article.tebyan.net/271727/%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%B1%D8%AD%D9%85-%D8%B4%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84-%D9%86%D8%B2%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%A8%D9%89-%D9%86%D9%85%D9%89-%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%AF-) (in Persian [Farsi])